# C# Asp Net Mvc,ViewBag

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mvc

привет.есть код контролера

```
SqlConnection sql;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            sql = new SqlConnection("Database=book;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Books", sql);
            var phonesTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(phonesTable);
            ViewBag.Books = phonesTable;
            //
            return View();
        }
```

я пытаюсь взять данный из базы MySql и вывести на страницу через ViewBag

в представлении у меня код

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Books)
            {

            <p>@b.name</p>
            <<p>@b.author</p>
            <p>@b.price</p>
            <p>@b.id</p>

    }
</div>
```

Ругается на  код в контролере вылетает исключение на строке

adapter.Fill(phonesTable);

И говорит Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта
adapter было null

Не пойму почему null
Помогите

Comment: код работоспособный но правда использовался для  wpf

Comment: где создается объект `SqlDataAdapter` и присваивается `adapter = ` и `adapter.SelectCommand = `? нигде! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Вы создали только переменную, но не проинициализировали ее, поэтому и NULL.  Попробуйте первой строчкой в метод  добавить инициализацию переменной **adapter**

Comment: При чем тут ViewBag - если до него даже не доходит?

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
```